# angularjs do orderBy after click the Header and not give default Header

Tags: angularjs

These are my headers:

```
<th ng-click="changeSort('header1')">header1</th>
<th ng-click="changeSort('header2')">header2</th>
<th ng-click="changeSort('header3')">header3</th>
```

and the table body:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in myArray | orderBy: sortValue : orderByDirection">
</tr>
```

my controller:

```
$scope.orderByField = 'num1';
$scope.orderByDirection = true;
$scope.myArray = [
    {num:1,key:x},
    {num:2,key:p},
    ...
];
$scope.sortValue = function(obj) {
    return obj.num;
}
$scope.changeSort = function(field) {
    if(field == $scope.orderByField) {
        $scope.orderByDirection = !$scope.orderByDirection;
    } else{
        $scope.orderByDirection = false;
        $scope.orderByField = field;
    }
};
```

Now,my question is that I don't want to order by when I open the page.
I have found if I don't init the `$scope.orderByField` the orderBy will not affect my default list. But angular still execute the orderBy method.

How can I do to prevent the execute when `$scope.orderByField` is undifined?

Comment: @user2341963 I don't know what happend after I approve your edit

Comment: How about adding `if (!$scope.orderByField)` to the `sortValue` function ?

Comment: I tried,angular still execute it's orderBy method.This doesn't affect the default list,but I just want to prevent the execute before I click any to-orderBy-header.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a function for ordering in your case. Just order by `orderByField`

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in myArray | orderBy: orderByField : orderByDirection">
```

Then in your controller, intialize it to nothing

```
$scope.orderByField = '';
```

When you click on the column header, change to order by your `num` property:

```
<th ng-click="changeSort('num')">header1</th>
<th ng-click="changeSort('num')">header2</th>
<th ng-click="changeSort('num')">header3</th>
```

EDIT: If you want to use your sort function you could try this.

Leave your repeat as is. Initialize your `orderByField` to nothing and change your sort function:

```
$scope.orderByField = '';
$scope.sortValue = function(obj) {
    return obj[$scope.orderByField] || obj;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a function because I have to transform some fields value to orderBy.